# How does block argument work in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and came across following snippet of code. class_a has a method, which takes some parameters and class_B.call method calls that method. 
but on the method call there is => {|_a, array_value| array_value['value'] = '1234'} 
after the method call, which i don't understand. when I hover over "_a" , it reads "unused block argument. 
what is this construct => {|_a, array_value| array_value['value'] = '1234'} , which is after the method call.

```
class_A
  class << self
    def method_A (count, *params) 
      #do soemthing
    end
  end
end

 class_B

  def call
    class_A.Method_A(20) {|_a, array_value| array_value['value'] = '1234'}
  end

 end
```

Comment: There’s a documentation for [block arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument). The underscore prefix is a convention to indicate an unused variable.

Comment: @Stefan - thanks for your comment. I had looked at block arguments, which is usually between do ...end construct. the snippet above places such argument right after a method call. I'm not sure how/what it does?

Comment: You probably missed this part (2nd paragraph): _"A block is sent to a method using `do ... end` or `{ ... }`"_ – your example method uses the latter form.

Comment: @Stefan - one thing I'm not clear on is , why do we need to pass an used variable when we call that method. when removed, the code doesn't work.